# How does the persistQueryClient from react-query work?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

I'm using React Query to make my API calls, but when I reload the page, the state is lost. I posted a question on StackOverflow asking if there is a way to persist data in react-query then someone responded saying that there is a way to do with persistQueryClient, but I tried reading the documentation and I still don't understand how it works. Can someone please explain to me?

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/plugins/persistQueryClient

Comment: Please share a link to the previous question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`persistQueryClient`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/plugins/persistQueryClient) is a wrapper around the standard `queryClient` that persists the cache to some form of storage e.g localStorage.

To define and use a `persistQueryClient`, we'll need to:

1. Create a query client with a large cache time.
2. Create a persister
3. Wrap both the query client and persister in a `persistQueryClient`.

An example provided by the [docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/plugins/persistQueryClient#persistqueryclientprovider):

```js
import { PersistQueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query-persist-client'
import { createSyncStoragePersister } from '@tanstack/query-sync-storage-persister'

// 1. the query client
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 24 hours
    },
  },
})

// 2. the persister
const persister = createSyncStoragePersister({
  storage: window.localStorage,
})

// 3. Replace the <QueryClientProvider> with <PersistQueryClientProvider>
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement).render(
  <PersistQueryClientProvider
    client={queryClient}
    persistOptions={{ persister }}
  >
    <App />
  </PersistQueryClientProvider>
)
```